# Haskell MaybeInt Query on elemIndex

Tags: haskell

I have the following function

```
eC :: Char -> [Char] -> Char
eC x z = z !! elemIndex x cA
```

Where cA is a list of chars.

However, I get returned

```
Type error in application
*** Expression     : z !! elemIndex x cA
*** Term           : elemIndex x cA
*** Type           : Maybe Int
*** Does not match : Int
```

I don't really understand what this means... Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 1):

This means that `elemIndex` returns `Maybe Int`, but you cannot use `Maybe Int` as the index in `!!`.

I am sure this can be solved simpler. I suggest looking into `zip` and `find`.

Edit: oooh, `zip` and `lookup` is even more straightforward in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`elemIndex` might fail, after all, the element may not be in the list. This failure mode should be in your final type (unless you handle it somehow).

```
eC :: Char -> [Char] -> Maybe Char
```

Then you can propagate the failure

```
eC x z = case elemIndex x cA of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  Just ix -> Just (z !! ix)
```

Though it's worth noting that `(!!)` will throw uncatchable exceptions if you have an out-of-bounds error. You may want to catch that as well by combining errors

```
eC x z = case elemIndex x cA of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  Just ix -> index z ix   -- index returns values wrapped in Maybe
```

You can do this more simply by using the `Monad` instance of `Maybe`.

```
eC x z = do ix <- elemIndex x cA
            index z ix
```

Or even

```
eC x z = elemIndex x cA >>= index z
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use just `Functor`

```
eC :: Char -> [Char] -> Maybe Char
eC x z = (z !!) `fmap` (elemIndex x cA)
```